# Iterate through pandas DataFrameGroupBy object to create yearly images with monthly subplots

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame with datetime index of hourly wind speed and direction. My timeseries covers 31 years and I need to make yearly images of monthly windroses. This translates into 31 images each with 12 subplots.

I have figured out how to get the windrose using the Windrose package. Using GroupBy I can group the data per year and/or month.

I've tried grouping by year and month, but couldn't figure out how to then iterate by year to make the monthly plots

```
grouped = data.groupby(by=[data.index.year, data.index.month])
```

Next I tried to make a for loop and group the data per year for each group

```
# Make lists of years and months
years = pd.Series(data.index.year).drop_duplicates(keep='first')
months = np.arange(1,13)

for year in years:
   yearly = data.groupby([data.index.year == year])
```

But this only grouped the data into observations in 2017, and observations not in 2017. If I then tried to filter to 2017 using:

```
for year in years:
    yearly = data.groupby([data.index.year == year]).filter(lambda x: data.index.year == 2017)
```

I get the error TypeError: filter function returned a ndarray, but expected a scalar bool

So at this point I want to be able to first iterate through years, then through months (per year) to eventually create yearly images with monthly subplots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
for year in years:
   yearly = data.groupby([data.index.year == year])
```

`yearly = data.groupby([data.index.year]` will group your data in years. You need to iterate through the different groups on yearly like so:

```
for name, group in yearly:
              ....
```

Documentation can be found  here:http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups

For monthly grouping you can do:

`yearly = data.groupby([data.index.year, data.index.month])` which will group each by year, then month.

Then to filter by each month and return only 2017 for example:

```
yearly = data.groupby([data.index.year, data.index.month]).filter(lambda x: x.index.year = 2017)
```

(on your code you used "date" instead of "x" in the lambda statement which is why it also failed).

Comment: Thanks for catching the error in my lambda function. But when I run 
`yearly = data.groupby([data.index.year, data.index.month]).filter(lambda x: x.index.year = 2017)` 

 I get `SyntaxError: lambda cannot contain assignment` 

Changing your code to `.filter(lambda x: x.index.year == 2017)`, I again get the error 

`TypeError: filter function returned a ndarray, but expected a scalar bool`

Comment: my mistake, in the filter statement change it to ```lambda x: (x.index.year == 2017).any()```